# Windows Disk Manager: how to remove the partition created by Ubuntu Installation?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with windows 7). But the installation failed due to a hard drive problem. Now in Windows disk manager there are three primary partitions. C belongs to Windows 7 and last 2 created during installation process. I want to delete the last 2 partitions. I want to know, if I delete them, will it affect the Windows boot loader?

Comment: You can delete the Ubuntu partition. The Windows boot loader does not depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just install something like partition wizard and delete the partition that Ubuntu was on, then resize/align the windows partition to fill the disk. You can do it all from within windows.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to do anything and everything with your hard disk. I would recommend using a partition manager like [EASUS Partition Manager](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html)

Once downloaded, simply install and delete or reformat rest of the partitions, don't touch the partition in which Windows is.

Note: Windows stores a additional partition of about 300 Mbs before the actual partition in which it is installed, please don't touch that as well.

Now, if you are insistent like me, to dual boot Ubuntu 14 with windows. Don't delete the partitions and install Ubuntu there next to windows ( or any partition that you  like). Make sure that partition is formatted with ext3 or ext4 filesystem before installing Ubuntu.

Once done, boot into windows. (normally you will not see any option to boot into ubuntu).

Now download [EasyBSD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and add Ubuntu partition in boot Entry.

Once completed with this simple step, reboot, this time you will have the option to select to boot into Windows or Ubuntu as per your intension.

If you need any help with dual boot, let me know. I am booting Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to revert to Windows entirely, so this is a bit off-topic for this forum.  That being said...

In Windows 7, click **'Start'**, *right*-click **'Computer'**, choose **'Manage'**. Under **'Disk Management'** you can view and alter the partitions on your hard disk there.